# Lodge Dutch Oven seasoning fail (My first cast iron experience)

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans, dutch-oven

I bought [this.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LEXR0K)

It was a little rusty. I cleaned the rust with salt. I wanted to remove preseasoning but I don't have requirements for that process.

1. Washed the dutch oven with soap and cold water.
2. Heated it to 100 C.
3. Applied flaxseed oil.
4. Wiped again with paper towel for excess oil.
5. Putted it to 250 C oven for 1 hour.
6. Waited 2 hours for cooling.

Problems:
1. Paper towel is not good for that because there are a lot of residue and dust on dutch oven when I use it.
  2. It seems 1st seasoning failed, because there is no change. Where I am wrong?

Rust:
[image: rust]

Before seasoning:
[image]

After seasoning:
[image]

Comment: @Stephie Yes. I will repeat it 5 times.

Comment: 2nd cylce is done. I didnt upload picture because 100% same :/

Comment: Is 250C as high as your oven will go?  Can you post a photo of the pan before it goes in the oven please?  I'm curious how much oil you are leaving on.

Comment: Is the problem spot only on the handle? What does the seasoning on the actual cooking surface look like?

Answer (score 1):

I always let some oil remain on the pan and as it burns off it leaves an almost non stick surface. Perhaps the paper towel is removing too much of the oil.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the self-cleaning oven cycle.  Take it out when cooled and wash down.

I tried flaxseed oil and wasn't impressed.  I mixed crisco, red palm oil, and grapeseed oil.  Put the pan in the oven at 200F for 10 mins.  Take it out and rub it down really well.  Now wipe it all off.  Think its all off? Take a paper towel and wipe it again.  Put it in the oven for 1 hour at 475 and let cool.  Repeat.

I'm a first time cast iron user and repeated this process 7 times with my 1st 2 new skillets and they came out gorgeous and completely non stick.  Then I restored 2 old pans and only did this process 3 times and they're both completely non stick and gorgeous.

Comment: I would add to this that you can also just get away with using Crisco on its own, without mixing anything. My mom showed me this, and I now use it on my pans and neither of us have had any issues with our pans.